# Return value in 'for' loop in nodejs backend

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm wondering if there is s possibility to return value on every loop iteration?

Something like this but in correct way:

```
for(....) {
    ...
    return value[i]
}
```

In my case I have an Angular app and nodeJs backend. In app I have subscription to function requesting a specific endpoint.

What I want to archieve is to return value on each loop iteration and show it in app.

I've already done that using websocket but I'm curious if there is any other way?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: That's a generator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators

Comment: returning a value will escape the loop. If you need the endpoint's data to be real time. websocket is the only way to go.
Unless you can wait till the loop iteration and return the values all at once